# How can I use Gwibber in 13.04?

Tags: gwibber, twitter, friends-app

I tried to use `gwibber` instead of `friends-app` in my Ubuntu 13.04 system.
I installed `gwibber` with

```
sudo apt-get install gwibber
```

The installation went fine but I can't run Gwibber with command `gwibber` nor can I find Gwibber while searching dash.

How can I use Gwibber with Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu does not come with Gwibber any longer; the package named "gwibber" (and some additional packages like "gwibber-service" are so called "transitional dummy packages" to facilitate the switch to friends-app. If you look at the Gwibber project's pages on Launchpad, the newest packages there are about two years old, so it seems to me you're out of luck, sorry.

Of course you can try to compile the old source code yourself, but I wouldn't recommend it. There probably are a lot of dependencies in that code that were satisfied on older systems but are not satisfied on current systems. So it would probably take *a lot* of work to get it to compile, without any guarantees that the resulting program will work in any decent manner.

If friends-app isn't your cup of tea, you might want to have a look at some other clients for your favorite social network that are out there. For Twitter, for example, there are [Polly](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/twitter-app-polly-adds-ubuntu-12-10-support) or [Birdie](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/new-linux-twitter-app-birdie), among others. They follow different concepts and are on different levels of stability/maturity, but are worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can install Gwibber in 13.04. I've unsuccessfully tried to install Gwibber some time back and found out that both Twitter's new API and OAuth standards are (obviously) not supported.

My suggestion is to go with the wave or if you're adventurous you can try Turpial or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you install Gwibber, like you did, you will have friends-app. That's exactly the same thing happened to me on 13.04.

Comment: Yes, but I was asking if it is possible to use gwibber?